# Retrieve $_POST data from a dynamic form

Tags: php, mysql

I have this page :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Aan.png]

When I click on the `Enregistrer` button I want to save all the modification I have made to the `Note` text fields.

Those text fields are generated with a select statement :

```
for($i=0; $i<$rows_number; $i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($students, $i, 'num_insc') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($students, $i, 'nom') . '</td>';
    echo '<td> <input style="text-align:center" type="number" name=note_"' 
        . mysql_result($students, $i, 'num_insc') . '" id="note" value="'
        .mysql_result($students, $i, 'note').'"> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

So the names of some `note` text fields are 'num_' + the `N° Inscription` that corresponds to this text field. For example, in the image you can see the `N° Inscription` of the first row is `1` so the name of the Note text field that corresponds to this row is 'num_1'.

When I click on the `Enregistrer` button the form data will be sent to the same page and I'm using $_POST to get those information.

But the problem is how can I retrieve the value of each text field and update the row in database that corresponds to this text field? Because the number of text fields varies and it changes depending on how many records there are in the database.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I know about PDO and I prefer working with it, but unfortunately we are studying PHP using mysql_*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two options:

1. Hide the original value in a `hidden` `input` field; then compare upon submission. This will reduce the overhead required with calling the original values from the database. However, this is less secure.
2. Fetch the original values and then compare the corresponding `$_POST` value.

Comment: but after submitting, how can I get the number of Note text fields from the $_POST array, and how can I retrieve them ?

Comment: @YukinaYukinatte Start out with `var_dump($_POST)`. This will show you exactly what is being posted.